# I want to retrieve data from an ArrayList using c#

Tags: c#

I want to retrieve object data from an  ArrayList;

```
public class Form1
{

 ArrayList list = new ArrayList();

private void OnSockMessage(object sender, SockEventArgs e)
 {

        Regex MyRegex = new Regex("^[<][A-Za-z]");
        if (e.SockMsg != null)
        {
            string y = e.SockMsg.ToString();

            if (MyRegex.IsMatch(y) == true)
            {

                rrr = y;
                string ipdd = SocClient[e.SocketRef].Soc.RemoteEndPoint.ToString();
                //serverkey seckey;
                list.Add(new serverkey(ipdd,rrr));


            }
            else
            {
                string curipadd = SocClient[e.SocketRef].Soc.RemoteEndPoint.ToString();

                for (int i = 0; i < list.Count-1; i++)
                {


                    //serverkey pk = list[i] as serverkey;
                    //string jj =  list[i].ToString();
                   // serverkey pk = new serverkey(list[i].ToString());

                   /*********************************************
                   here i want to retrieve data from array list
                   *********************************************/
                   string ipadd;


                    if (curipadd == ipadd )
                    {
                        y = DecryptString(e.SockMsg, rrr);
                        listBox1.Items.Add(txtIP.Text + " <<" + y);

                    }
                }

            }
        }

public class serverkey : Form1
    {
        string ipaddress;

        string secertkey;


        public serverkey(string IPAdd, string Seckey)
        {
            ipaddress = IPAdd;
            secertkey = Seckey;
        }
 public string ip

        {
            get { return ipaddress; }
        }
  public string key
        {
            get { return secertkey; }
        }
```

Comment: What's the question?  I just see code.

Comment: the question was in the code..

Comment: see "here i want to retrieve data from array list" in the code

Comment: Try again.  Post only the relevant bits of code and post the actual question **outside** of the code so potential answerers don't have to go hunting for the question.  The easier you make it on those who can help, the more help you will get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd be better off using a strongly typed generic `List<serverkey>` and a foreach loop rather than a for loop. It'll be something like

```
List<serverkey> list = new List<serverkey>();

//add your items as you already are

foreach(var item in list)
{
   item.ip ...// use item as a serverkey
}
```

Having said that, if you can you use a generic for some reason, use an 'as'

ArrayList list = new ArrayList();

```
//add your items as you already are

foreach(var item in list)
{
   var sk = item as serverkey;
   sk.ip ...// use item as a serverkey
}
```

Comment: No, don't use `as`.  For the love of $DEITY, don't.  In this case, using `as` means that "item was not a string" is **indistinguishable** from "item was a null object reference."  You'd rather see a ClassCastException if the cast can't be performed than a NullReferenceException at some point later. *Only* use `as` if you are unsure of the type of the object, and then always follow it *immediately* with a null check.  (Unless you are passing the result to a method where the behavior of passing in a null reference is acceptable.)

Comment: Fair enough generally. As I said, personally I think a strongly typed generic collection is the best solution. but in this case we're certain of the type. I guess a hard cast would also be just as valid.